# Problem comparing elements in a Pandas dataframe Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I'm working with a kaggle dataset which looks like this:

```
df1.head()
```

[image]

```
df2.head()
```

[image]

Basically the two `dataframes` `df1` and `df2` have been read from different files and have some values common. I want to get the indices of the values which are same in the `EssayText` column of both dataframes.

Right now I'm doing this:

```
[(True, i) for i,text in enumerate(df2['EssayText']) if text in df1['EssayText']]
```

But this returns no output, while I have seen that at least top 5 values are exactly same in `df1` and `df2`.

I also tried `df1['EssayText'][0] in df2['EssayText']` and surprisingly this returns `False`. I don't seem to understand the reason.

On the flip side, if I do something like:

```
df1.iloc[3] == df2.iloc[3]
```

The output I get is

```
    Id           True
EssaySet     True
Score1       True
Score2       True
EssayText    True
Name: 3, dtype: bool
```

Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance:)

Comment: please provide us with code to recreate your data, e.g. `df.to_dict()` (truncated as needed)

Comment: Thats because it is comparing indexes of the series (I suppose) that are returned when you index dataframes that way. So use .values at the end of each data frame indexing, such as df1['key'].values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is I think simpler than you think..
You can use **masking** like this to get the indices where both df1 and df2 have identical values for '**EssayText**' column.

```
commonIndices = df1[df1['EssayText']==df2['EssayText']].index.to_list()
```

or

```
commonIndices = df2[df2['EssayText']==df1['EssayText']].index.to_list()
```

Either way, the result will be the same

Answer (score 2):

Please try below code for the problem you have mentioned.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = [[1,1,1,1,"A"],[2,1,1,1,"B"],[2,1,1,1,"C"],[2,1,1,1,"D"]]
data2 = [[2,1,1,2,"A"],[2,1,1,1,"B"],[2,1,1,1,"C"],[2,1,1,1,"E"]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1,
                   columns=["Id","EssaySet","Score1","Score2","EssayText"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2,
                   columns=["Id","EssaySet","Score1","Score2","EssayText"])
l_match = []
for index,rowdf1 in df1.iterrows():
    indexdf1 = int(index)
    for index,rowdf2 in df2.iterrows():
        indexdf2 = int(index)
        if (rowdf1["EssayText"] == rowdf2["EssayText"]):
            l_match.append((indexdf1,indexdf2))
print(l_match)
```

Output:

```
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this seems a bit complicated to me. My problem got solved by just adding `.values` as suggested by @Carafini